# Unit Testing a Request in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for this method, but I can't figure out how to setup the `Request`. Specifically, I need to set `Query` and the header attribute `Referer`.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    var query = Request.Query;
    StringValues returnUrlValue;
    if (query.TryGetValue("returnUrl", out returnUrlValue))
    {
        var returnUrl = returnUrlValue.ToString();
        var referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
        {
            returnUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(referer);
        }

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

I understand that a `request` goes through the middleware before ever getting to the controller, so it can't be passed into the controller as a parameter. But, the `Request` object on the controller is `readonly` and cannot be assigned. Therefore something like the following won't work.

```
var controller = new LoginController();
controller.Request = new DefaultHttpRequest(new DefaultHttpContext())
{
    QueryString = new QueryString("?returnUrl")
};
```

Comment: Pass it via the `HttpContext` which can be mocked to take the request

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one mentioned, as it also asks how to set the query, which is what I'm looking for. Should be unflagged as a duplicate.